# Installing kubernetes on localhost using LXD

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernetes on localhost using LXD but facing issue. I am using conjure-up for this but on proceeding localhost option is not highlighted stating that LXD not found.

**[Error]**

[image]

I have installed LXD as per commands given. Do I need to provide path somewhere so that conjure-up finds the path or is there some other issue?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install lxd
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
sudo lxd init --auto
/snap/bin/lxc network create lxdbr0 ipv4.address=auto ipv4.nat=true ipv6.address=none ipv6.nat=false
conjure-up kubernetes
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I had to `sudo apt purge lxd` first

Then
`sudo apt upgrade`

After installing lxd as suggested on conjure

`sudo snap install lxd`

`/snap/bin/lxd init`

Disabled IPV6 with the wizard

And then `conjure-up`

Don't forget to logout and login after adding the user to the group
(I actually did a reboot)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to create an LXD "dir" storage.  Else no pods will launch correctly.  This is a known issue with conjure-up.  You can specify this when you run lxd init.

https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/spellbooks/kubernetes#limitations